# ROS1 to ROS2 Dynamic Bridge Error: Failed Bridge Creation for '/rosout' Topic

Tags: ros, ros2, remapping, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

" failed to create 2to1 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ros2type 'rcl_interfaces/Log' and Ros1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log' "

this is the error i obtained while running the $ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge.
please help me to rectify this error. if message remapping is need how can we done remapping.

rcl_interfaces/Log  TO  rosgraph_msgs/Log    remapping is special case i think why because,  the data types and number of variables are not equal...
your  answer is most helpful to me ..please answer
THANK YOU.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323120/i-got-an-error-when-interfacing-ros-1-with-ros2-through-dynamic-bridge-i.e..,%22-failed-to-create-2to1-bridge-for-topic-%27/rosout%27-with-ros2type-%27rcl_interfaces/log%27-and-ros1-type-%27rosgraph_msgs/log%27-%22./) by [roslearnersai](https://answers.ros.org/users/40990/roslearnersai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a know issue, see https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/159

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0